# losing scope array data data when changing step form to previous step

Tags: angularjs

I saving Data in multiple steps form at my last step i m using array data in scope when i click previous button at last step of array data form data lost from scope.

I have a ng-repeat displaying a list of data with an input each. I want to be able to push the value of each input together with a parameter from every item into a new array.

```
     # This is my script #
     <script>   
        $scope.submitted = true;
        var arr = [];

        for(var i=0; i<$scope.choices.length; i++)  {
            arr.push({
                items: $scope.choices[i].items,
                no_of_cartoons: $scope.choices[i].no_of_cartoons,
                size: $scope.choices[i].size,
                volume: $scope.choices[i].volume
            });
            var myJSON = JSON.stringify(arr);
        }

        var res = $http({
            method: 'POST',
            url:_url+"function_ajax.php",
            headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'},
            transformRequest: function(obj) {
                var str = [];
                for(var p in obj)
                str.push(encodeURIComponent(p) + "=" + encodeURIComponent(obj[p]));
                return str.join("&");
            },
            data: 
            {
                surveyHomeContrl:true,
                invData: myJSON,
                last_id:$scope.last_id
            }
        });
        res.success(function(html) {
            if(html=='1')
            {   
                $scope.isLoading = false;   
                alert("Survey Complete");
                location.href = "#/view-Survey";
            }
            else  
            {
                alert("Error, Try again.");
                $scope.isLoading = false;
            }
        });
        res.error(function(html) {
            alert('Please connect to internet.');
            $scope.isLoading = false;
        });
        };
      </script>


        # This one is my html Code #
<form role="form" id="formpadd" name="formhome" class="" method="post" action="" ng-submit="formhome.$valid && surveyHomeFn()">
    <input type="hidden" ng-model="last_id" name="last_id" value="{{last_id}}" />
    <fieldset ng-repeat="choice in choices">
        <div class="span4 " ng-class="{true: 'error'}[submitted && formhome.item.$invalid]">
            <label>Items</label>
            <span class="input input--kozakura">
                <input class="input__field input__field--kozakura feildname" type="text" name="item" placeholder="Items" ng-model="choice.items"
                    ng-required="true">
                <span class="err" ng-show="(formhome.item.$dirty || submitted) && formhome.item.$error.required">item is Required</span>
            </span>
        </div>
        <div class="span4" ng-class="{true: 'error'}[submitted && formhome.no_of_cartoons.$invalid]">
            <label>No. of Cartoons</label>
            <span class="input input--kozakura">
                <input class="input__field input__field--kozakura feildname" type="number" name="no_of_cartoons" placeholder="No. of Cartoons"
                    ng-model="choice.no_of_cartoons" ng-required="true" />
                <span class="err" ng-show="submitted && formhome.no_of_cartoons.$error.required">No. of Cartoon is Required</span>
            </span>
        </div>
        <div class="span4">
            <label>Size</label>
            <span class="input input--kozakura">
                <input class="input__field input__field--kozakura feildname" type="text" name="size" placeholder="Size" ng-model="choice.size"
                />
            </span>
        </div>
        <div class="span4">
            <label>Volume</label>
            <span class="input input--kozakura">
                <input class="input__field input__field--kozakura feildname" type="text" placeholder="Volume" ng-model="choice.volume" />
            </span>
        </div>
        <button type="button" class="remove" ng-click="removeChoice($index)">
            <i class="fa fa-minus" aria-hidden="true"></i>
        </button>
        <button type="button" class="addfields remove" ng-show="$last" ng-click="addNewChoice()">
            <i class="fa fa-plus" aria-hidden="true"></i>
        </button>
    </fieldset>
    <div class="span3">
        <button class="w-button action-button" type="submit" name="surveyController" ng-show="$last" ng-click="setTab(3)">
            <i class="fa fa-arrow-circle-left fa-lg"></i> Previous</button>
    </div>
    <div class="span3">
        <button class="w-button action-button" type="submit" ng-click="submitted=true" name="surveyHome">Save </button>
    </div>
</form>
```

Comment: can you share complete controller code?

Comment: why needs complete controller?

Answer (score 0):

I just have to check that scope of array exist or not

```
if($scope.choices == 'undefined'){
    $scope.choices =  [{items: '', no_of_cartoons: '', size: '',volume: ''}];
    $scope.len = 1; 
}
```